# JQuery Grid addRowData Error

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I recently upgraded to latest jqGrid  4.8.2 .

When i am trying to add a row it is throwing up the following error.

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

The Error is generated at the following location in the Jquery.JQgrid.min.js

[image]

The value passed are as follow :

a=1, b= {} , c='last' and d=0

Am i doing something wrong here ?

the project is in VS2010 MVC 3

**EDIT :**

This is how i call it :

> g.addRowData(id + 1, datarow, 'last',id);

Comment: first of all there are two forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which latest version is 4.9.1 and [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) which you use. If you have an error then you should use non-minimized version (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.js` depond on the fork and version which you use) to report the error. You should also post **your code** which use jqGrid, at least the code fragment which call `addRowData` and the value of input parameters so that other could reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg Hi Oleg i call it like  g.addRowData(id + 1, datarow, "last",id); By the way i downloaded it from trirand.com  which is showing as latest in that page

Comment: Which web browser you used in your test? Is it some old IE browser?

Comment: By the way one need to call `addRowData` very seldom. It's not good for example to fill the grid by calling `addRowData` in the loop. To be exactly the way is the most slow way to fill the grid which I know. If you fill the grid from `mydata` array then it's better to use `data: mydata` parameter, which allows *to create and fill the grid at the same time*. It's the moistly effective way to create and fill the grid.

Comment: In a master-detail form when a user adds a record, i append it to the grid. Is there any other way ?

Comment: There are many ways. You should just describe more detailed in separate new question what you need exactly and what you do currently in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop alternative fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)) starting with changing license agreement of jqGrid 4.7.1. I fixed many old bugs and implemented many new features. I verified that I changed [the first line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.8.2/js/grid.base.js#L3560) of `addRowData`

```
if(["first", "last", "before", "after"].indexOf(pos) == -1) {pos = "last";}
```

to the following

```
if ($.inArray(pos, ["first", "last", "before", "after", "afterSelected", "beforeSelected"]) < 0) { pos = "last"; }
```

because some old web browsers don't have `indexOf` method of Array. You can make the same modification in your non-minimized copy of `jquery.jqGrid.js` or just use free jqGrid 4.9.1. You can try it just changing the URLs to CDN urls described in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: i am sure i will try it Oleg. By the way i use IE8 in a Win7 Box. Is there any major feature differences in between yours and Guriddo versions? Also  it will be great if you include property and method documentations in the github.  Thank you by the way.

Comment: @Deb: The [readme 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README48.md), [readme 4.9](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README49.md), [readme 4.9.1](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.9.1/README.md) together with [many wiki articles](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) described new features. I had no time to create separate site with new documentation, but I tried till now to hold compatibility with old versions of jqGrid (<=4.7).